# Is there any optimal time to check ipfs-hash exist or not?

Tags: validation, hash, ipfs

[ipfs object stat](https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-object-stat):

> 'ipfs object stat' is a plumbing command to print DAG node statistics.
>  is a base58 encoded multihash.

If given hash is valid, it returns some information (if and only if shared node's `ipfs daemon` is on).

```
$ ipfs object stat QmNd4PHGU8Z7fwbEvps5jvVscCDd5husnNgKpaDCfm1tpt
NumLinks: 0
BlockSize: 39
LinksSize: 2
DataSize: 37
CumulativeSize: 39
```

Now I try it with an invalid hash or node (which shares the ipfsHash)'s `ipfs daemon` is off: I observe that the command halts.

```
$ ipfs object stat QmNd4PHGU8Z7fwbEvps5jvVscCDd5husnNgKpaDCfm1t88 #invalid hash
#waits.
```

If I enter an invalid has into `ipfs object stat` it pauses. I can do `timeout N` to terminate it: But I am not sure how long should I wait.

```
timeout 30 ipfs object stat QmNd4PHGU8Z7fwbEvps5jvVscCDd5husnNgKpaDCfm1t88
```

Overall, I just want to check does given `ipfs-hash` exists for me to retrieve its information.

**[Q]** Is there any optimal time for me to wait until `ipfs object stat <ipfsHash>` returns a valid value or not? Would around 30 seconds to wait be enough?

Please note that:  I tried between node in Europe and node in States, it took around 120 seconds on first try. But after I assume a path route is generated between those nodes, my next try with different hash between same nodes takes less than a second. What might be the reason for this?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what would cause a delay like that, but there have been a lot of improvements to the DHT since 2017 I'd imagine. What's happening is your node is effectively looking and asking around "who has this CID?". Once it finds who has the CID, it retrieves it from that node directly p2p (or using [p2p-circuit](https://docs.libp2p.io/concepts/circuit-relay/)).

I don't think there is a perfect "optimal time", so you'd have to decide what feels acceptable to you I suppose. By the sounds of it 150-180 seconds should be somewhat reasonable if you're expecting delays up to "around 120 seconds". In 2021 I rarely run into big delays like this, but it's not completely unheard of if the data is **only** on a node with a restrictive NAT for example. I personally usually give up around the 30s mark, but if I'm relatively sure the data is difficult to retrieve, I'll sometimes leave it try indefinitely until I eventually get the data I'm looking for.

As for why it's so fast after for retrievals from the same node, you've either now peered with them (likely), or another node that's peered with them retrieved their data and has it in their cache (like a gateway for example). So your node is probably aware of them and likely the CIDs they claim to have, so it's able to find and retrieve the data much quicker.